# Why is this function a modular function of level $5$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Suppose we have a function $\phi\colon \mathfrak H \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ such that

1. $\phi^{24}$ is a modular function of level $5$.
2. $\phi(\tau)=\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty}a_{n}q^{n/5}$, $a_{-1}\neq 0,q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$.

Does it follow that $\phi$ is a modular function of level $5$?

In particular, I am interested in the function
$$\phi(\tau)=-\frac{1}{5^{1/2}}\frac{\eta(\tfrac{\tau}{5})\eta(\tfrac{\tau+1}{5})\eta(\tfrac{\tau-1}{5})}{\eta(5\tau)\eta(\tfrac{\tau+2}{5})\eta(\tfrac{\tau-2}{5})}.$$
Is there a a simple way to show that it is modular of  level $5$?  [Siegel](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01425549) says that it is easy to show that it is so. We could compute the generators for $\Gamma(5)$ and then use the transformation formula for the Dedekind eta function, but this seems like a mess.

Comment: $j(z/5)(1-1728/j(z/5))^{1/24}$ is not a modular function, it has a branch point at $5i$

Comment: Just a remark, I would say you dont' need generators of $\Gamma(5)$. Usually to show modularity, one just takes any $\gamma$ in $\Gamma(5)$, work out the transformation formula, and use the congruence conditions on the coefficients. You could also look at Yifan Yang, [Transformation formulas for generalized Dedekind eta functions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870805001714). This is probably still complicated. I don't know what "easy" means to Siegel.

Comment: There's a nice answer here for a similar question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297049/is-eta-tau2-a-modular-form-of-weight-1-on-gamma12?rq=1
In particular there's reference to a book by Ken Ono containing some theorems that might interest you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward way to show that $\phi$ is modular of level $5$ using Siegel functions.

**Claim**: The function $f(\tau)$ is a modular function for $\Gamma(5)$ if and only if $f(5\tau)$ is a modular function for $\Gamma_{0}(25) \cap \Gamma_{1}(5)$. (This is straightforward to prove using properties of the slash operator.)

Using this claim, it's not hard to see that $\eta(\tau/5)/\eta(5\tau)$ is a modular function of level $5$, using the standard result of Gordon, Hughes and Newman about when an eta quotient is modular of level $N$. (This result can be found in the [Wikipedia article about the Dedekind $\eta$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).)

It remains to show that $\frac{\eta(\frac{\tau+1}{5})\eta(\frac{\tau-1}{5})}{\eta(\frac{\tau+2}{5})\eta(\frac{\tau-2}{5})}$ is a modular function of level $5$.

The Siegel functions $g_{(a_{1}/N,a_{2}/N)}$ can be used to build modular functions of level $N$. (See Section 5 of the article [here](https://afolsom.people.amherst.edu/Folsom-JNTB-publ.pdf) by Amanda Folsom that gives a product expansion of the Siegel functions and criteria of Kubert and Lang that indicate when a product of Siegel functions is modular.) The product formula implies that
$$
  g_{(0,a_{2}/N)}(\tau) = c \eta(\tau + a_{2}/N) \eta(\tau - a_{2}/N)
$$
for some constant $c$. The modularity criteria imply that
$$
  h(\tau) = \frac{g_{(0,1/5)}(\tau)}{g_{(0,2/5)}(\tau)} = \frac{\eta(\tau + 1/5) \eta(\tau - 1/5)}{\eta(\tau + 2/5) \eta(\tau - 2/5)}
$$
is a modular function for $\Gamma(5)$. Now $h(\tau) = h(\tau + 1)$ and so $h(\tau)$ is a modular function for $\left\langle \Gamma(5), \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle = \Gamma_{1}(5)$. Since $\Gamma_{0}(25) \cap \Gamma_{1}(5) \subset \Gamma_{1}(5)$, the claim above implies that $h(\tau/5)$ is a modular function for $\Gamma(5)$ and this proves that $\phi$ is a modular function of level $5$.

As a note related to your first question about $\phi^{24}$ being modular of level $5$ implying $\phi$ is modular of level $5$, Theorem 1 of Kubert and Lang's paper [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01361857.pdf) is the following. Let $N$ be a prime power and $U_{N}$ be the group of modular units of level $N$ that are generated by the Siegel functions. If $g$ is a modular function and there is a positive integer $k$ so that $g^{k} \in U_{N}$, then $g \in U_{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate the reference to Kubert-Lang.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that if $\ell>3$ is a prime, all modular units of level $\ell$ are generated by the Siegel functions, so we may apply this to the function $\phi$ and similar eta-quotients of higher (prime) level?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The modular units in $U_{\ell}$ have full rank within the group of level $\ell$ modular units. This forces $U_{\ell}$ to have finite index in the group of modular units, and Theorem 1 of Kubert and Lang's paper implies the index is $1$.